# How many COVID tests do I need for trip to UK?

Tags: covid-19, england, wales

Next month I'm visiting England and Wales. Here's a rough timeline of the trip:

1. Arrive in England on Thursday and spend the night at my girlfriend's house.
2. Take a train to Wales on Friday to visit a friend.
3. Return to England via train on Sunday and stay there for a full week.

Do I need to fill out multiple Passenger Locator Forms since I will travel to England, then Wales, then back to England?

How many COVID tests do I need to take? I have one scheduled for Thursday when I land, one on Friday when I arrive in Wales, and one for the return flight to the US. Do I need an additional test when returning to England on Sunday?

Comment: What's your vaccination status (number, type, country of administration)?

Comment: @MadHatter I qualify as fully vaccinated and will arrive before Feb 11th (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travel-to-england-from-another-country-during-coronavirus-covid-19#changes-to-international-travel-rules-from-11-february-2022)

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No. There are no Red List countries at the moment. (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/red-list-of-countries-and-territories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of writing there are no restrictions of any form when traveling between England or Wales. You do not need a test or to fill out a passenger locator form. However, covid rules in England and Wales are different once you arrive, and activities permitted in one may not be permitted in the other.

You mention you are traveling by train, be aware that many rail companies are still operating a reduced service.

Source: my own recent experience

I'll leave the arriving into England section for anyone that knows the current rules better. However, you do have to consider that you're day 2 test might be positive, you will be required to declare where you will be self isolating on the passenger locator form. Any positive results are automatically reported to the NHS. I'd highly encourage you to have a plan in advance for what you are going to do if this happens.